# Cannot send email in C# on Server 2008, but works on Windows 7

Tags: .net, email, iis, smtp, windows-server-2008

I have code that uses System.Net.Mail.MailMessage to send an email on port 587 via smtp.gmail.com.  When I run this code via IIS on my computer with Windows 7, it works.  The email gets sent, and it arrives.

The same exact code running on IIS on Windows Server 2008 does not work.  All things held constant, the only difference is the operating system.  It's all running on the same network, so it's not a router security issue.  I've attempted to disable the outgoing firewall on port 587, but that did not work.  I have attempted to apply the answers in the following two questions, but those didn't work either:

[Sending email through a Google Apps account is working locally, but not on my web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039089/sending-email-through-a-google-apps-account-is-working-locally-but-not-on-my-we)

[c# SmtpClient class not able to send email using gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311749/c-sharp-smtpclient-class-not-able-to-send-email-using-gmail/1312095#1312095)

Anybody have any idea what security setting on Windows Server is preventing me from sending emails?

The error I get: 
The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp.gmail.com'

Comment: Can the host name be resolved? Open a command prompt and type nslookup smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Just a sanity check: ping smtp.gmail.com does yield results?

Comment: nslookup smtp.gmail.com does not work.  The response is "UnKnown can't find smtp.gmail.com: No response from server"

Comment: ping smtp.gmail.com also gets no response

Comment: DNS problem? Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Yeah, the site itself is up and running on IIS.  It's just the email sending code that breaks every time.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem yesterday and i found the solution right now ,it is too late but hope this help some one else 
see this [link](http://threadstate.com/2012/05/07/sputility-sendemail-problem-in-custom-activity-use-smtpclient/) ,the lines that you need is

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                {
                    return true;
                };
```

and

```
 Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@zzz.ccc", "sdfsdf")
```