# Unable to send email in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web-config, smtp

I understand this topic has been well elaborated previously, but I have looked around the Internet for various solutions and nothing has helped so far.

I'm making a web application which at one point is supposed to send an email to the email that the user provided. I'm trying to send it from my gmail account.

I tried the following:

```
public void test()
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mygmail@gmail.com", "password*"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send("mygmail@gmail.com", "mygmail@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And I'm getting the following error: `The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.`

In my web.config file I wrote

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="smtp.google.com" password="" userName=""/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
```

But that didn't work. I also tried adding the `password*` and the username (`mygmail@gmail.com`) in the web.config instead of the empty strings for `userName` and password, but I still got the same error.

Could anyone please help me out?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting UseDefaultCredentials to false before specifying your custom credentials.
See [c# SmtpClient class not able to send email using gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311749/c-sharp-smtpclient-class-not-able-to-send-email-using-gmail)

Comment: It's fine it worked. I always post a question on Stack Overflow and then figure it out on my own immediately. It's embarrassing. The problem was that I have 2 step verification set up on that account that I was testing with and because of that I couldn't log in. So I made a new basic account and it worked like charm with that. I'll accept your answer as the right one though. Since you're probably trying to get more reputation just like I am. Thank you for responding!