# SmtpException while sending Email

Tags: c#, email, smtpexception

I am trying to send Email through my C# code but I am getting `SmtpException`

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.194.67.109:587

Here is how I am sending Email:

```
string HostAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
msg.Subject = "Test Email";
msg.Body = "Hi testing invoice";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("ramshaafaq2012@gmail.com"));
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = HostAddress;
client.EnableSsl = true;
NetworkCredential creadit = new NetworkCredential();
creadit.UserName = msg.From.Address;
creadit.Password = Password;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Credentials = creadit;
client.Port = 587;
client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Did you have a look at SmtpException.InnerException as it could contain more detailed information.

Comment: Do you test this code behind a proxy? If so did you configure your program to use it? Maybe a firewall is blocking your request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# SmtpClient class not able to send email using gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311749/c-sharp-smtpclient-class-not-able-to-send-email-using-gmail)

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia even the solution recommended in that post  doesn't work

Comment: @PhilippGrathwohl I think I have VPN installed on my machine.How should I configure my program for that?

Comment: You can configure it in your app.config. Have a look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6484zdc1.aspx

Comment: What should I configure? `<defaultProxy>` or `<mailSettings>`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Credentials = creadit;
```

You are specifying a set of credentials but you are *also* telling `SmtpClient` to use the default credentials (i.e. the Windows username and password of the logged-in user). Set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false and it will use your supplied credentials instead.