# Visual C# SmtpClient could never get authenticated

Tags: c#, authentication, credentials, host, smtpclient

I have tried gmail, yahoo, and hotmail hosts, and I'm 100% sure that my username and password is correct. But no matter how I tried, I could NEVER get my credential authenticated.

It keep showing me this error:

[image]

The Chinese part roughly means "SMTP Server Required a Secure Connection, or the Client Credential is not Authenticated. Server Replies: 5.7.1"

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Verify that port 587 exists through your network administrator.

Comment: My code looks similar, except I don't have client.EnableSsl = true; and it works.

Comment: I added those codes latter one by one after the first 2000 tries had failed! So... it still won't work without those parts! >"<

Comment: Gmail is using a security approach when less secure apps want to access. Did you try to ON the "Allow less secure apps" in your gmail?

Comment: Stop pasting images, its annoying, paste code and errors messages

Comment: @TraxX: I DID go enable the option! And it STILL can NOT be authenticated!!! WHY!?!?!?

Comment: No its not a third-party app. It is in the google security options. Go to myaccount.google.com > Sign in & Security > Apps with Account access.

Comment: @Michael: Annoying!? Can you tell me why!? And why do they offer the option if we are NOT allowed to use it!?!?!?

Comment: Restart your app after turning ON the option.

Comment: @Pikachu620 The option is primarily for the need to show content that cant be put into text. search engines cant search text in images. and its annoying because  its hard to read, you cant copy and paste the code to test it. ect ect ect

Comment: @Michael: I got your point! Will improve upon it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your `client.Credentials` after `client.UseDefaultCredentials`

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new blabla;
```

Just rearrange the codes something like you are composing email.

```
From
To
Subject
Email Body
```

then your `Port, UseDefaultCredentials, Credentials` and last one is `Send`

You have to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311749/c-sharp-smtpclient-class-not-able-to-send-email-using-gmail?rq=1) similar to your problem.