# sending email in asp.net using web config

Tags: c#, asp.net

please guide me what to write in web config file in c# for email sending.

```
  <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="yourdomain.com">

  </smtp>
</mailSettings
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068611/how-to-send-an-email-from-my-c-sharp-codebehind-getting-system-net-mail-smtpfa) page?

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
        <network
          host="localhost"
          port="25"
          defaultCredentials="true"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx