# How can I use Google to send email?

Tags: c#, winforms, email

i created a window app which send email to a particular email id which is inserted in my textbox,

here is my code on my button click

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", textBox1.Text, "here is the subject of the mail", textBox2.Text);
            SmtpClient mail = new SmtpClient();
            mail.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            mail.Port = 465;
            mail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "senderpassword");
            mail.EnableSsl = true;
            mail.Send(msg);
            MessageBox.Show("message has been sent to the mail provided");

        }
```

i am getting an error message which is written below

> 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

please let me know what is the issue which i am facing

Comment: Have you *checked* GMail's documentation for the correct settings? GMail doesn't use port 465. In any case, you should post the *full* exception, not only the message.

Comment: try using 587 port

Comment: Furthermore, there are dozens of similar SO questions, that include links to GMail's documentation and explain what is required, eg when you need an authorization key and how to bypass it

Comment: Also check [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757987/send-email-via-c-sharp-through-google-apps-account). The top answer shows how you can specify the server settings in the application's configuration. Note that you can add the `enableSsl="true"` attribute in the config file as well